# Solidify faces as separate objects that touch

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, faces

I have a mesh objects with faces. I would like to create separate objects for each face but solidify them at the same time while they still touch eachother. For a cube I could do this in the following way:

1. Create cube mesh
2. In `edit` mode, use `Edge split` (search 'Edge split')
3. Extrude `E`, but cancel immediately
4. Scale `S` (larger or smaller doesn't really matter)
5. Select all faces `A` and separate `P` > `As loose parts`

The result is something like this where each face is now a thick version of itself with bevelled edges that touch (one side removed to highlight the internals, but these are 6 separate objects).

[image]

However, due to the way in which scaling works, this does not work well for convex shapes. The scaling scales to the center of the object instead of along the normals.

[image]

I also tried extrude along normals, but this loses the shape due to the `edge split`. Somehow is does not exactly the same as scale and extrudes the exact shape of the face outwards (instead of keeping the edges together).

Which method could I use to achieve the desired effect for freeforms?

Comment: Are you looking for a solidify modifier followed by an edge split modifier (at 180 degrees)?

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>  to begin scaling along normals.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't give the desired result after the edge split which I need to obtain the separate objects. After edge split, in the scaled version the edges don't stick together anymore.